# Get the time difference in hh:mm between two datetimes using moment

Tags: momentjs

I am having issue with getting the time difference between two timestamps (epoch format).

I used `moment().format("L LT")` to convert it into desired datetime format (`MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM (12 hour)`),
but now the problem is, I want the difference between the times in `hh:mm`

P.S.: it can be more than 24 hours too.

What I tried:

```js
let timeDiffms,duration,timedifference,
start moment(startTimeStampInMS).format("L LT"),
end = moment(endTimeStampInMS).format("L LT");

timeDiffms = moment(end, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm").diff(moment(start, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"));
duration = moment.duration(timeDiffms);
timedifference = Math.floor(duration.asHours()) +":"+duration.minutes();  // result

//output I am getting  
// start = "03/20/2017 3:11 PM" end="03/21/2017 9:45 AM" timedifference = "30:24", (incorrect)
// start = "03/20/2017 10:07 AM" end="03/23/2017 11:24 AM" timedifference = "73:17" (correct)
// start = "03/20/2017 3:11 PM" end="03/23/2017 11:31 AM" timedifference = "80:20" (incorrect) strange
```

I don't know what is happening wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the previous answer given, I was able to workaround on same logic and get the correct solution for my question.

```js
let start moment(startTimeStampInMS),
end = moment(endTimeStampInMS);

let timediffms = end-start;    // difference in ms
let duration = moment.duration(timediffms);
 // _data should not be used because it is an internal property and can 
 //change anytime without  any warning 
//let hours = duration._data.days*24 + duration._data.hours; 
//let min = duration._data.minutes;
let hours = duration.days()*24+ duration.hours();
let min = duration.minutes();
timeDifference = hours +":"+ min;  // Answer
```

Comment: Do not use `_data`, it's an [internal property](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/), use [`days()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/), [`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/),  [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your current solution you are formatting a moment object as string and then parse the string back to moment to get `diff`. There is no need to do this two-step process, you can do the following to get the duration:

```js
start moment(startTimeStampInMS),
end = moment(endTimeStampInMS).format("L LT");

timeDiffms = end.diff(start);
duration = moment.duration(timeDiffms);
```

Or since your input is in milliseconds:

```js
moment.duration(endTimeStampInMS - startTimeStampInMS);
```

To get `duration` in the `HH:mm` format you can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) plug-in that adds the `format` method to duration object.

Here a working sample:

```js
// Example milliseconds input
let startTimeStampInMS = 1490019060000;
let endTimeStampInMS = 1490085900000;
// Build moment duration object
let duration = moment.duration(endTimeStampInMS - startTimeStampInMS);
// Format duration in HH:mm format
console.log( duration.format('HH:mm', {trim: false}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer , but i wanted with pure moment js , without using any plugin.